# Delayed documentation citation reputation

Tags: support, documentation

Recently I got +5 reputation point due to a citation of a documentation topic

[image]

However "[no recent changes](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41846259/timeline)" has been made to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846259/uncorrect-result-of-query/41846599#41846599) the last months. The [most recent change](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41846599/revisions) was by the community bot which has changed the http links to https

Did the bot triggered the reputation change? Did I regain the reputation points for a second time (I do not remember if got them on the first place)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reputation for citing a topic or an example is awarded when someone upvotes the answer that has the link to Documentation. In this case, an upvote came in at 7:54 on May 31, which then triggered the +5 rep award to you as a major contributor on the Union topic.

Normally, I'd expect you to have received that rep on the first upvote on the answer back in January. However, we had a bug in doc link tracking that prevented accurate recording of citations that were present in the initial revision of answers. Funnily enough, I fixed that issue on January 26, just one day too late for you to get the rep on first upvote.

I thought I backfilled the link data correctly (which should have retroactively awarded you +5 rep), but it looks like I missed something. Either way, mystery solved!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am adding here the link for the [answer's timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41846599/timeline) which clearly show the upvote. I certainly missed that in the first place. I was looking for any activity in question's timeline instead of the answer's